# Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined in Webpack Tapable

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack, webpack-2

I have recently upgraded from Webpack v1 to v2 and I am getting following error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
at Compiler.apply (C:\sample\node_modules\Tapable.js:375:16)
```

Comment: Why don't you upgrade to v4?

Comment: I was trying to use [webpack-cli migrate command](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli#migration-from-webpack-v1-to-v2) which migrates my config file to v2 compatibility. I will eventually convert it v4.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have double comma in your plugins setup in webpack.
I had issue something like this...

```js
 extractSass, // first semi
 ,new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({ // second semi in this line
      analyzerMode: 'static'
  })
```

Or  try running `yarn add extract-text-webpack-plugin@next`